# QGridLayout doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm building gui for my project using Qt5.5 and trying to use QGridLayout.

### First source

This code worked as I expected.

```
QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout;
layout->addWidget(lineEdits[0], 0,0,1,1);
layout->addWidget(lineEdits[1], 0,1,1,1);

layout->addWidget(lineEdits[2], 1,0,1,1);
layout->addWidget(lineEdits[3], 1,1,1,2);

layout->addWidget(lineEdits[4], 2,0,1,2);
layout->addWidget(lineEdits[5], 2,2,1,1);
this->setLayout(layout);
```

Here is the result I got.

[image: First case]

### Second source

But this code generated broken layout and that was very far from what I expected.

```
QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout;
layout->addWidget(lineEdits[0], 0,0,1,1);
layout->addWidget(lineEdits[1], 0,1,1,2); //this is the only difference

layout->addWidget(lineEdits[2], 1,0,1,1);
layout->addWidget(lineEdits[3], 1,1,1,2);

layout->addWidget(lineEdits[4], 2,0,1,2);
layout->addWidget(lineEdits[5], 2,2,1,1);
this->setLayout(layout);
```

[image]

I have no idea about how to fix this.

I would appreciate for your suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there's nothing that gives the middle column any significant width - it's there but the only thing that makes it visible is the inter-column spacing, which is why the last row doesn't align with the other two.

One way to fix this is to set the column [stretch](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch) factors. For example, try this (same factor for all columns, the actual number doesn't matter, only the proportion does):

```
//...
layout->addWidget(lineEdits[5], 2, 2, 1, 1);
for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
  layout->setColumnStretch(i, 1);
this->setLayout(layout);
```

This gives me the following layout:

[image]

Another option is to force one of the multi-column widgets' widths explicitly, but better avoid that if you can.

Comment: Thanks. Perfect answer.